# I want to put divs with the class "height_mark" every 980px from the bottom of the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's what I have:

Javascript(with a jquery library in the header):

```
    var prev_height=0;
    for (var i=0; i<=100; i++) {
        prev_height+=980;
        $("body").append("<div class='height_mark' style='bottom:"+prev_height+"px'>"+(i)+"</div>");
    }
```

CSS:

```
.height_mark {
  position: absolute;
  left:300px;
  height:20px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

What I want to do:
I want to put a div with the class "height_mark" every 980px from the bottom of the webpage.

Problem: 
for some reason, it doesn't show the height marks.

Answer (score 0):

Use "margin-top" instead of "bottom" in the JS and define the amount of margin for each div that gets added (also wrap it in a function and make sure to call the function):

```
let winHeight = 0;
let margin = 980;

function addDivs(){
    for (var i=0; i<=100; i++) {
        winHeight+=980;
        $("body").append("<div class='height_mark' style='margin-top:"+margin+"px'>"+(i)+"</div>");
    }
    }

addDivs()
```

and use position:relative in the css:

```
.height_mark {
  position: relative;
  left:300px;
  height:20px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

codepen:

https://codepen.io/pen/bGVNYmm